# Using wxAny as a container class for wxControls

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Can the wxAny class be used to store a wxCheckBox class or other wxControl based classes?

```
wxPanel *panel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
wxCheckBox test(panel, idMenuAbout + 1, wxT("Show title"), wxPoint(20, 20));
wxAny checkBox = test;
```

The above code generates the error `'wxCheckBoxBase& wxCheckBoxBase::operator=(const wxCheckBoxBase&)’ is private`

Thanks.

Comment: WTF do you want to do? wxAny isn't some sort of GUI control. It's the wx version of boost::any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with `wxAny` but with the fact that `wxCheckBoxBase` is made non-copyable:

wx/checkbox.h

```
class WXDLLEXPORT wxCheckBoxBase : public wxControl

protected:

     DECLARE_NO_COPY_CLASS(wxCheckBoxBase)
}
```

wx/defs.h

```
/*  --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/*  macro to define a class without copy ctor nor assignment operator */
/*  --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#define DECLARE_NO_COPY_CLASS(classname)        \
private:                                    \
    classname(const classname&);            \
    classname& operator=(const classname&);
```